# Castle Windsor: So what DOES ActAs do?

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, fluent-interface

I noticed that the castle windsor fluent component registration interface has the rather confusing ActAs() method.

Googling around for it the only reference I found was at their wiki [here](http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/Fluent+Registration+API).

> TODO (Stuff that could be documented)
>
> - what does ActAs() do?

Not too helpful.

The source doesn't seem to have any unit tests for the method that would give a clue to its usage and I'm too unfamiliar with their source to be able to tell for myself what is going on.

Does anyone know any more about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It [adds custom dependencies (tags)](http://fisheye2.atlassian.com/changelog/castleproject?cs=4961) to the component being registered. The [WcfFacility](http://www.castleproject.org/container/facilities/trunk/wcf/index.html), for example, [uses these attached dependencies](http://fisheye2.atlassian.com/browse/castleproject/trunk/Facilities/Wcf/Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration/Service/WindsorServiceHostFactory.cs?r=5525#l93) to [set up endpoints and other stuff](http://fisheye2.atlassian.com/browse/castleproject/trunk/Facilities/Wcf/Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.Tests/Rest/RestServiceFixture.cs?r=5525#l36).